# Why is AWS Sumerian transitioning to Babylon.js? Any alternative AWS services planned in future?

Tags: amazon-web-services, babylonjs, amazon-sumerian

The AWS Faqs : https://aws.amazon.com/sumerian/faqs/ Suggest the AWS Sumerian is going to transition to BABYLON.JS.
However, why is AWS planning to sunset this Service ?
Is there any new AWS service planned to be release for future ?
Any drawbacks identified in AWS Sumerian ?

What are the alternatives to AWS Sumerian ? Are the aletrnatives easier to utilize than the Babylon.js tarnsitioned version ? Any percentage of users consuming the altervatives